# UseSelector passing down props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Hello I have this `useSelector()` within my parent component:

```
const initialFormState = useSelector((state) => state.form.initialForm);
```

I'm trying to pass the above into my custom component, like so:

```
<CustomButtons data={initialFormState}/>
```

However within that component above I cannot seem to `console.log` my state, rather it comes back as defined.

```
const CustomButtons = (props) => {

  const { error, submitting } = useFormState();

  console.log("state =>" + props.data);

  return (
    <Grid item container>
      <Grid item>
        <Button type="submit" disabled={error || submitting}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

How can I access `props.data` here?

Comment: Did you mean `undefined` rather than `defined`?

Comment: Well, are you sure `initialFormState` is something else than `undefined` in the first place?

Comment: Are you sure you added it to the redux store?